# Alter location of edge in graph in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-graphs

So I have the following:

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[shorten >=1pt,node distance=1.75cm,thick]
        \node (A) {$A$};
        \node (B) [below left of=A] {$B$};
        \node (C) [below right of=A] {$C$};

        \path   (A) edge (B)
                (A) edge (C);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

This produces the following image:

[image]

What I'd really like though is where the edges meet below the nodes:

[image]

Is there a way to alter the edge locations so that they met underneath a node rather than to the unit circle surrounding the node?

Comment: `\path   (A.south) edge (B.north)    (A.south) edge (C.north);`

Comment: Didn't realise you could add parameters to a variable name like that o_O Good to know though =) Thanks! Worked just the way I wanted it to =D

Comment: @KevinC, an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One can refer to a named node's anchors by using the syntax `(<name>.<anchor>)`. In your case,

```
\path   (A.south) edge (B.north)    (A.south) edge (C.north);
```

would produce the desired edges.